# python :: howto parse json and access element

Tags: json, python-2.7

I am trying to parse a json that in the raw form look like this :

```
{'OK': True, 'Value': 43768746}
```

i am doing this :

```
line = line.strip().decode("utf-8")  
j_proper = json.dumps(line)  
j = json.loads(j_proper)  
print  j['Value']
```

but i get the error :

```
print  j['Value']  
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

if i print line, j_proper, j and their types i get this :

```
{'OK': True, 'Value': 43768746}  
< type 'unicode'>  
"{'OK': True, 'Value': 43768746}"  
< type 'str'>  
{'OK': True, 'Value': 43768746}  
< type 'unicode'>
```

What is the correct recipe to parse such a json and access the "Value" number?
Thank you!

Comment: Why not refer to the received structure as regular dictionary?

Comment: can you elaborate on your question? do you mean to try j_proper['Value'] ? i get the same error like with j

Comment: also, i would like to know why my question was down voted.. i researched the subject to the best of my abilities and did not succeed to reach my goal ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JSON string is incorrect. The proper format would be:

{"OK": true, "Value": 43768746}

Changes:

- double quotes instead of single quotes
- lower "t" instead of "T" for "true"

Example:

line = '{"OK": true, "Value": 43768746}'
j = json.loads(line)

{u'OK': True, u'Value': 43768746}

j['Value'] = 43768746
j['OK'] = True

Comment: I tried to edit and clean up the input and i have now this : {"OK": true, "Value": 43814485}
"{\"OK\": true, \"Value\": 43814485}"
{"OK": true, "Value": 43814485}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dirac.status_list.py", line 29, in <module>
    print j_proper['Value']
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str

Comment: ok, i eliminated the json.dumps and the clean up line went well with json.loads directly. Thank you!!